# comparing request.time to value set using toMillis() in firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following code and I want to compare 2 values and set rules accordingly, but apparently there is no consistency between the two, at least the comparation is not working issue was I want to make all timestamps stored in ms.

```js
// Data Filed set in cloud fuction.
const expiresIn = 3600; // test 1h   //172800  === 48h
const createdAt = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toDate();
createdAt.setSeconds(createdAt.getSeconds() + expiresIn);

premiumUntill: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(createdAt).toMillis()


// Rules
&& request.auth.token.premiumUntill > request.time
&& resource.data.premiumUntill > request.time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[request.time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) is a [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp) object, not time in millis.  It's not directly comparable to an integer.

If you want to use request.time in rules, you should store a Firestore Timestamp object in the document field for direct comparison.  Or you can convert the rules Timestamp to millis first before comparing it to an integer.

Comment: How to convert the rules Timestamp to millis ? like this ? request.time.toMillis() inside rules if this is the case then rules have access to method which is awesome ?

Comment: Click through to the API docs I linked for Timestamp for details on how to use it.